Need help in importing dynamic images using Vite
I need help to implement dynamic image imports using vite. I had a look into other solutions but cannot understand those, unless the solutions are in my own code.
The problem starts here:

I have an array of objects that have the following structure:
{
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "xx59-headphones",
    "name": "XX59 Headphones",
    "image": {
      "mobile": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/mobile/image-product.jpg",
      "tablet": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/tablet/image-product.jpg",
      "desktop": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/desktop/image-product.jpg"
    },
    "category": "headphones",
    "categoryImage": {
      "mobile": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/mobile/image-category-page-preview.jpg",
      "tablet": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/tablet/image-category-page-preview.jpg",
      "desktop": "./assets/product-xx59-headphones/desktop/image-category-page-preview.jpg"
    },
}


My file tree is the following, where in the assets directory I have the folder structure of the images that I am about to import:
├── src
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── Layouts
│   │   └── MaxWidthLayout.tsx
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── audiophile.png
│   │   ├── cart
│   │   │   ├── image-xx59-headphones.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-xx99-mark-one-headphones.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-xx99-mark-two-headphones.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-yx1-earphones.jpg
│   │   │   ├── image-zx7-speaker.jpg
│   │   │   └── image-zx9-speaker.jpg
│   │   ├── checkout
│   │   │   ├── icon-cash-on-delivery.svg
│   │   │   └── icon-order-confirmation.svg
│   │   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── desktop
│   │   │   │   ├── image-earphones-yx1.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── image-header-removebg-preview-mobile.png
│   │   │   │   ├── image-hero-removebg-preview.png


The third part is to create a component to use this URL. I used import.meta.url:
function getImgUrl(name: string) {
        let image = new URL(`/src/assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href;
        console.log(image);
        return image;
    };

    return (
        <article className="p-5">
            <MaxWidthLayout>
                <div className="border-4 border-red-500">
                    <aside className="border-4 border-blue-600">
                        <img src={getImgUrl(mobileImage)} alt="Detailed image product" />
                    </aside>
                    <aside className="border-4 border-green-600">
                        {/* You can add other elements here */}
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </MaxWidthLayout>
        </article>


Not working, the URL was incorrect:
http://localhost:5173/src/pages/ProductDetail/components/assets/product-zx9-speaker/mobile/image-category-page-preview.jpg

Instead of pointing to src/assets, so I modified it.
   function getImgUrl(name: string) {
        let image = new URL(`${name}`, import.meta.url).href;
        let splittedImage = image.split('/pages/ProductDetail/components').join('');
        console.log(splittedImage)
        return splittedImage;
    };



I don't understand. I followed some tutorials, and still didn't managed to render the images. Apart of this, I get no error so I don't know where to start looking to..

You can make /src/assets into /src/public/assets, then the assets will appeared at http://<VITE_SERVER>/assets/...

You meant to replace in the string? Because I cannot see any public folder into my dist file.

I mean static assets handling

yes. this is what I'm trying to do. But failed

Have you tried using a relative path for your url? Instead of /src/assets/${name}, try ../assets/${name} (adjust depending on your script location). Double dots are used for moving up in the hierarchy, a single dot represents the current directory.

I tried. The problem is serve package is looking into the dist folder to serve statically images. And my images are not getting coppied.
I found an ugly solving. I moved everything into root dir, public folder. Now I'm getting a total mess in the dist folder, but at least my images works in production... Should I leave it like this?
